# I cannot install Ruby's DevKit well on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby

[image]

I'm on windows 8.1 x64

I cannot install ruby DevKit well, what to do next?

```
ruby -v

1.9.2p290<2011-07-09[i386-mingw321]>
```

I want to configure octopress, seems stuck here now.

```
----"E:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rdiscount-2.1.6\ext\mkmf.log"


have_func: checking for random()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:53: error: 'random' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))random; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
E:\Users\HYPERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cce9IqGL.o: In function `t':
E:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rdiscount-2.1.6\ext/conftest.c:8: undefined reference to `random'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { random(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for srandom()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:53: error: 'srandom' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))srandom; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
E:\Users\HYPERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccumIxqZ.o: In function `t':
E:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rdiscount-2.1.6\ext/conftest.c:8: undefined reference to `srandom'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { srandom(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rand()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rand; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for srand()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib      -lmsvcrt-ruby191-static  -lshell32 -lws2_32  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))srand; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

check_sizeof: checking size of unsigned long... -------------------- int

"gcc -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: typedef unsigned long rbcv_typedef_;
6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
7: 
8: /*top*/
9: int conftest_const[(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)) == sizeof(int)) ? 1 : -1];
/* end */

--------------------

check_sizeof: checking size of unsigned int... -------------------- int

"gcc -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IE:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: typedef unsigned int rbcv_typedef_;
6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
7: 
8: /*top*/
9: int conftest_const[(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)) == sizeof(int)) ? 1 : -1];
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Have you checked the `mkmf.log` file for more details?

Comment: @Leif added, help so see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Ruby 1.93, some tutorials are too old, and I've installed Ruby 1.93, then it's ok Now.